# Sleeping time range when using sauce lab driver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver, saucelabs

I am using sauce Lab driver for my selenium test cases.  In one of my test case, I need to have the process to take 1 minute sleep, before continuing the rest steps.  And I have seen much higher % of random failure for this case, with the message such as:

`The test with session id ... has already finished, and can't receive further commands...`

Was that because it takes too much time to run, and the session timed-out by sauce-lab ?

Usually I have tens of test cases running in one single-thread way, and every test class handles the driver by itself, such as:

```
public class TestASuite extends TestBase { 
    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun=true)
    public void setup(...) {
        // driver starts here... 
    }
    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void closeSession(ITestContext test) {
        // driver ends here 
    }
    public void testCase1(){}
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change your sauce lab config for handling such timeouts.
Please refer this to understand how things work.
[SauceLab Selenium Timeouts](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Test+Configuration+Options#TestConfigurationOptions-Timeouts)

`commandTimeout` is the param actually, you are looking for and need to change.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way that I can adjust the sauceLab timeout value on the fly ? I may just have couple cases need to have a longer one, but I could not find a sample to follow.

Comment: these should be part of your capabilities as stated in documentation.

Comment: Also these are timeouts and as per timeout functionality it would not delay your execution if expectation is fulfilled before time.